# Rails with Phusion Passenger fails to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this. I'm encountering a error while trying to deploy my rails app to a server (ubuntu 14.04). I'm using nginx and phusion passenger to serve the app. Passenger is reporting the following:

I'm not using rvm. I've installed ruby from source.

```
[ 2014-11-18 17:29:16.5595 1703/7f76f0885700 agents/HelperAgent/RequestHandler.h:2306 ]: [Client 20] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is cce1b2a5. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 5834 stdout: 
App 5834 stderr: /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb: No such file or directory - hostname
App 5834 stderr: sh: 1: env: not found
App 5834 stdout: 
[ 2014-11-18 17:32:35.6801 1703/7f76f2bfa700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:287 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/app/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: 414aebf5
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-ROvpCg.html
  Message from application: undefined method `strip' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mlanett-redis-lock-0.2.6/lib/redis-lock.rb:20:in `<class:Lock>'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mlanett-redis-lock-0.2.6/lib/redis-lock.rb:6:in `<class:Redis>'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mlanett-redis-lock-0.2.6/lib/redis-lock.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/chewy_kiqqer-0.2.4/lib/chewy_kiqqer/worker.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/chewy_kiqqer-0.2.4/lib/chewy_kiqqer.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
  /var/www/app/releases/20141118154027/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/www/app/releases/20141118154027/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /var/www/app/releases/20141118154027/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
  /var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `eval'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:112:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Where are you deploying? Do you know where the env binary is on your machine?

Comment: @darrint can you be more specific?

Comment: The app is deployed to `/var/www/app/current` which is a symlink to `/var/www/app/releases/20141118154027`. The bundle folder within the app is symlinked to `/var/www/app/shared/bundle` so that gems don't have to be re-installed between deployments

Comment: @darrint I believe the env binary is at `/usr/bin/env`. This command '/usr/bin/env ruby -v' (run by my deployment user) returns the following: `ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]`